# Using jest with babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I was using react-scripts only for tests, and want to get rid of it. I tried to recreate the `test` script, but it didn't work the way I expected.

Here's my `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
};
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    ["@babel/preset-typescript", { "onlyRemoveTypeImports": true }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-rename-import",
      {
        "replacements": [
          {
            "original": "^(.+?)\\.svg$",
            "replacement": "$1.js"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "**/*.svg"
  ]
}
```

And when I run `jest`, I get this error:

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /home/aironside@ant.local/Documents/microfrontends_libs/react-components/src/lib/components/molecules/empty/__specs__/Empty.spec.tsx:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Any idea how what I'm missing here?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not